# Why does Forticlient VPN stops connecting at 98%?

Tags: vpn, forticlient

I'm using free version of FortiClient VPN (v6.4.3.1608) to connect to my company's VPN. Once in a while, my connection would drop automatically when there's a bad network or when I put my computer to sleep. Most of the time when I try to reconnect back, it would get stuck at 98% (see below) for half a minute
[image]

Then, it would fail silently and clear the Password field.

[image]

## My VPN Settings

[image]

## FortiClient Error logs (last 50 lines)

**NOTE#1:** I have replaced sensitive data in the logs with the words REDACTED.

**NOTE#2:** The last 17 lines (starting from `fortissl_connect: device=ftvnic`) are my attempts in trying to reconnect to VPN unsuccessfully.

**NOTE#3:** I believe the connection was dropped at this line `Ras: connection to fortissl terminated`

```
...
02/07/2021 14:01:57 info    sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 19960: Ras: connection to fortissl terminated
02/07/2021 14:01:57 error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 32052: Error find interface for local_gwy 160aa8c0
02/07/2021 14:01:57 error   sslvpn  (repeated 1 times in last 1 sec) FortiSslvpn: 32052: Error find interface for local_gwy 160aa8c0
02/07/2021 14:02:00 info    system  date=2021-07-02 time=14:01:59 logver=1 id=96900 type=traffic subtype=system eventtype=traffic level=info uid=UID_REDACTED_FOR_STACKOVERFLOW devid=DEVID_REDACTED hostname=redacted-laptop pcdomain=redacted.pvt deviceip=RED.DAC.T.22 devicemac=Re-da-ct-ed-22-33 site=N/A fctver=6.4.3.1608 fgtserial=DEVID_REDACTED emsserial=N/A os="Microsoft Windows 10 Professional Edition, 64-bit (build 19041)" user=ricardo@REDACTEDCOM msg="Traffic log" sessionid=306713590 srcname=sslvpn srcip=RED.DAC.T.22 srcport=0 direction=outbound dstip=vpn.REDACTEDCOM.net dstport=10443 proto=6 rcvdbyte=112206696283 sentbyte=51564226372 utmaction=passthrough utmevent=vpn threat=disconnect userinitiated=0 browsetime=0
02/07/2021 14:48:05 info    system  date=2021-07-02 time=14:48:04 logver=1 id=96823 type=systemevent subtype=system eventtype=status level=info uid=UID_REDACTED_FOR_STACKOVERFLOW devid=DEVID_REDACTED hostname=redacted-laptop pcdomain=redacted.pvt deviceip=RED.DAC.T2.139 devicemac=Re-da-ct-ed-22-22 site=N/A fctver=6.4.3.1608 fgtserial=DEVID_REDACTED emsserial=N/A os="Microsoft Windows 10 Professional Edition, 64-bit (build 19041)" user=ricardo@REDACTEDCOM msg="Checking for updates"
02/07/2021 14:48:50 info    update  date=2021-07-02 time=14:48:49 logver=1 id=96819 type=systemevent subtype=update eventtype=status level=info uid=UID_REDACTED_FOR_STACKOVERFLOW devid=DEVID_REDACTED hostname=redacted-laptop pcdomain=redacted.pvt deviceip=RED.DAC.T2.139 devicemac=Re-da-ct-ed-22-22 site=N/A fctver=6.4.3.1608 fgtserial=DEVID_REDACTED emsserial=N/A os="Microsoft Windows 10 Professional Edition, 64-bit (build 19041)" user=ricardo@REDACTEDCOM msg="Update was successful to the given version for the given module"
02/07/2021 14:48:50 info    update  date=2021-07-02 time=14:48:50 logver=1 id=96819 type=systemevent subtype=update eventtype=status level=info uid=UID_REDACTED_FOR_STACKOVERFLOW devid=DEVID_REDACTED hostname=redacted-laptop pcdomain=redacted.pvt deviceip=RED.DAC.T2.139 devicemac=Re-da-ct-ed-22-22 site=N/A fctver=6.4.3.1608 fgtserial=DEVID_REDACTED emsserial=N/A os="Microsoft Windows 10 Professional Edition, 64-bit (build 19041)" user=ricardo@REDACTEDCOM msg="Update was successful to the given version for the given module"
02/07/2021 14:51:14 info    sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 24572: fortissl_connect: device=ftvnic
02/07/2021 14:51:16 error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 23844: error: unexpected 512 bytes read before tunnel start.
02/07/2021 14:51:16 error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 23844: error: SslBlockingWrite() - Unknown error = 5
02/07/2021 14:51:16 error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 23844: error: ssl_connect:1
02/07/2021 14:51:16 error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 23844: tunnel_to_fgt error
02/07/2021 14:51:19 error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 39664: error: ras_loop(), waitResult=1.
02/07/2021 15:02:15 info    sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 19120: fortissl_connect: device=ftvnic
02/07/2021 15:02:18 error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 24308: error: unexpected 512 bytes read before tunnel start.
02/07/2021 15:02:18 error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 24308: error: SslBlockingWrite() - Unknown error = 5
02/07/2021 15:02:18 error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 24308: error: ssl_connect:1
02/07/2021 15:02:18 error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 24308: tunnel_to_fgt error
02/07/2021 15:02:20 error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 10084: error: ras_loop(), waitResult=1.
02/07/2021 15:03:48 info    sslvpn  date=2021-07-02 time=15:03:47 logver=1 id=96602 type=securityevent subtype=sslvpn eventtype=status level=info uid=UID_REDACTED_FOR_STACKOVERFLOW devid=DEVID_REDACTED hostname=redacted-laptop pcdomain=redacted.pvt deviceip=RED.DAC.T2.139 devicemac=Re-da-ct-ed-22-22 site=N/A fctver=6.4.3.1608 fgtserial=DEVID_REDACTED emsserial=N/A os="Microsoft Windows 10 Professional Edition, 64-bit (build 19041)" msg="SSLVPN service started successfully" vpnstate=
02/07/2021 15:03:53 info    system  date=2021-07-02 time=15:03:51 logver=1 id=96823 type=systemevent subtype=system eventtype=status level=info uid=UID_REDACTED_FOR_STACKOVERFLOW devid=DEVID_REDACTED hostname=redacted-laptop pcdomain=redacted.pvt deviceip=RED.DAC.T2.139 devicemac=Re-da-ct-ed-22-22 site=N/A fctver=6.4.3.1608 fgtserial=DEVID_REDACTED emsserial=N/A os="Microsoft Windows 10 Professional Edition, 64-bit (build 19041)" msg="Checking for updates"
02/07/2021 15:13:15 error   sslvpn  date=2021-07-02 time=15:13:14 logver=1 id=96603 type=securityevent subtype=sslvpn eventtype=error level=error uid=UID_REDACTED_FOR_STACKOVERFLOW devid=DEVID_REDACTED hostname=redacted-laptop pcdomain=redacted.pvt deviceip=RED.DAC.T2.139 devicemac=Re-da-ct-ed-22-22 site=N/A fctver=6.4.3.1608 fgtserial=DEVID_REDACTED emsserial=N/A os="Microsoft Windows 10 Professional Edition, 64-bit (build 19041)" user=ricardo@redacted.pvt msg="SSLVPN tunnel connection failed" vpnstate= vpntunnel="REDACTEDCOM VPN SG" vpnuser=ricardo remotegw=vpn.REDACTEDCOM.net
02/07/2021 15:13:31 info    sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 17004: fortissl_connect: device=ftvnic
02/07/2021 15:13:31 info    sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 16988: PreferDtlsTunnel=0
02/07/2021 15:13:35 info    system  date=2021-07-02 time=15:13:34 logver=1 id=96900 type=traffic subtype=system eventtype=traffic level=info uid=UID_REDACTED_FOR_STACKOVERFLOW devid=DEVID_REDACTED hostname=redacted-laptop pcdomain=redacted.pvt deviceip=RED.DAC.T2.139 devicemac=Re-da-ct-ed-22-22 site=N/A fctver=6.4.3.1608 fgtserial=DEVID_REDACTED emsserial=N/A os="Microsoft Windows 10 Professional Edition, 64-bit (build 19041)" user=ricardo@REDACTEDCOM msg="Traffic log" sessionid=1144101873 srcname=sslvpn srcip=RED.DAC.T.45 srcport=0 direction=outbound dstip=vpn.REDACTEDCOM.net dstport=10443 proto=6 rcvdbyte=4294968532 sentbyte=7113 utmaction=passthrough utmevent=vpn threat=connect userinitiated=0 browsetime=0
02/07/2021 15:13:35 info    sslvpn  date=2021-07-02 time=15:13:35 logver=1 id=96600 type=securityevent subtype=sslvpn eventtype=status level=info uid=UID_REDACTED_FOR_STACKOVERFLOW devid=DEVID_REDACTED hostname=redacted-laptop pcdomain=redacted.pvt deviceip=RED.DAC.T2.139 devicemac=Re-da-ct-ed-22-22 site=N/A fctver=6.4.3.1608 fgtserial=DEVID_REDACTED emsserial=N/A os="Microsoft Windows 10 Professional Edition, 64-bit (build 19041)" user=ricardo@redacted.pvt msg="SSLVPN tunnel status" vpnstate=connected vpntunnel="REDACTEDCOM VPN SG"
02/07/2021 20:48:03 info    system  date=2021-07-02 time=20:48:02 logver=1 id=96823 type=systemevent subtype=system eventtype=status level=info uid=UID_REDACTED_FOR_STACKOVERFLOW devid=DEVID_REDACTED hostname=redacted-laptop pcdomain=redacted.pvt deviceip=RED.DAC.T.45 devicemac=Re-da-ct-ed-22-33 site=N/A fctver=6.4.3.1608 fgtserial=DEVID_REDACTED emsserial=N/A os="Microsoft Windows 10 Professional Edition, 64-bit (build 19041)" user=ricardo@REDACTEDCOM msg="Checking for updates"
02/07/2021 20:48:31 info    update  date=2021-07-02 time=20:48:30 logver=1 id=96819 type=systemevent subtype=update eventtype=status level=info uid=UID_REDACTED_FOR_STACKOVERFLOW devid=DEVID_REDACTED hostname=redacted-laptop pcdomain=redacted.pvt deviceip=RED.DAC.T.45 devicemac=Re-da-ct-ed-22-33 site=N/A fctver=6.4.3.1608 fgtserial=DEVID_REDACTED emsserial=N/A os="Microsoft Windows 10 Professional Edition, 64-bit (build 19041)" user=ricardo@REDACTEDCOM msg="Update was successful to the given version for the given module"
02/07/2021 20:48:30 info    update  (repeated 1 times in last 0 sec) date=2021-07-02 time=20:48:30 logver=1 id=96819 type=systemevent subtype=update eventtype=status level=info uid=UID_REDACTED_FOR_STACKOVERFLOW devid=DEVID_REDACTED hostname=redacted-laptop pcdomain=redacted.pvt deviceip=RED.DAC.T.45 devicemac=Re-da-ct-ed-22-33 site=N/A fctver=6.4.3.1608 fgtserial=DEVID_REDACTED emsserial=N/A os="Microsoft Windows 10 Professional Edition, 64-bit (build 19041)" user=ricardo@REDACTEDCOM msg="Update was successful to the given version for the given module"
02/07/2021 21:09:01 info    sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 13484: Ras: connection to fortissl terminated
02/07/2021 21:09:01 error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 16960: Error find interface for local_gwy 2d0aa8c0
02/07/2021 21:09:01 error   sslvpn  (repeated 1 times in last 1 sec) FortiSslvpn: 16960: Error find interface for local_gwy 2d0aa8c0
02/07/2021 21:09:03 info    system  date=2021-07-02 time=21:09:02 logver=1 id=96900 type=traffic subtype=system eventtype=traffic level=info uid=UID_REDACTED_FOR_STACKOVERFLOW devid=DEVID_REDACTED hostname=redacted-laptop pcdomain=redacted.pvt deviceip=RED.DAC.T.45 devicemac=Re-da-ct-ed-22-33 site=N/A fctver=6.4.3.1608 fgtserial=DEVID_REDACTED emsserial=N/A os="Microsoft Windows 10 Professional Edition, 64-bit (build 19041)" user=ricardo@REDACTEDCOM msg="Traffic log" sessionid=1144101873 srcname=sslvpn srcip=RED.DAC.T.45 srcport=0 direction=outbound dstip=vpn.REDACTEDCOM.net dstport=10443 proto=6 rcvdbyte=4493243094 sentbyte=50396290 utmaction=passthrough utmevent=vpn threat=disconnect userinitiated=0 browsetime=0
02/07/2021 21:17:27 info    sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 6216: fortissl_connect: device=ftvnic
02/07/2021 21:17:30 error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 4348: error: unexpected 512 bytes read before tunnel start.
02/07/2021 21:17:30 error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 4348: error: SslBlockingWrite() - Unknown error = 5
02/07/2021 21:17:30 error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 4348: error: ssl_connect:1
02/07/2021 21:17:30 error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 4348: tunnel_to_fgt error
02/07/2021 21:17:32 error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 16448: error: ras_loop(), waitResult=1.
02/07/2021 21:18:20 info    sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 23560: fortissl_connect: device=ftvnic
02/07/2021 21:18:22 error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 21232: error: unexpected 512 bytes read before tunnel start.
02/07/2021 21:18:22 error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 21232: error: SslBlockingWrite() - Unknown error = 5
02/07/2021 21:18:22 error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 21232: error: ssl_connect:1
02/07/2021 21:18:22 error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 21232: tunnel_to_fgt error
02/07/2021 21:18:25 error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 17672: error: ras_loop(), waitResult=1.
02/07/2021 21:19:45 info    sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 24152: fortissl_connect: device=ftvnic
02/07/2021 21:19:47 error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 23772: error: unexpected 512 bytes read before tunnel start.
02/07/2021 21:19:47 error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 23772: error: SslBlockingWrite() - Unknown error = 5
02/07/2021 21:19:47 error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 23772: error: ssl_connect:1
02/07/2021 21:19:47 error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 23772: tunnel_to_fgt error
02/07/2021 21:19:49 error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 10176: error: ras_loop(), waitResult=1.
```

Answer (score 1):

I found these workarounds by accident.

#### Workaround #1

Either sign-out and sign-in to Windows again or restart your PC.

#### Workaround #2

Go to Internet Options > Connections > LAN Settings and uncheck *Use a proxy server for your LAN*. I found that this is checked whenever I turned on Capturing Traffic in Telerik's Fiddler.

[image]

Granted, there still remains the "why" but I hope this answer will help someone just in case.