# FortiClient VPN Stuck at 98% - Seeking Resolution

Tags: vpn, forticlient

I'm currently facing an issue with my FortiClient VPN, where it consistently gets stuck at 98% during the connection process. Despite numerous attempts, I haven't been able to pinpoint the root cause or find a solution.

Here are some details about my setup:

- FortiClient version: 7.2.2.0864
- Operating System: Windows 11
- Network configuration: Customized port 10443

Steps I've already taken to troubleshoot:

1. Restarted the FortiClient application.
2. Restarted my computer.
3. Have enabled Forticlient Console, FortiClient Installer, FortiClient Network services, FortiClient security, FortiClient Securtiy console to communicate through windows Defender firewall, private and public.
4. Have reinstalled FortiClient

I have attached the last few lines of the log files- if that helps to identify the issue.

---

Despite these efforts, the issue persists, and I'm unable to establish a successful VPN connection. If anyone has experienced a similar problem or has insights into possible solutions, I would greatly appreciate your guidance.

Additionally, if there are specific logs or diagnostic tools within FortiClient that could help diagnose this issue, please advise on how to access and interpret them.

```
11/30/2023 9:13:42 AM   info    update  date=2023-11-30 time=09:13:41 logver=1 id=96819 type=systemevent subtype=update eventtype=status level=info uid=*************** devid=FCT************* hostname=SYT pcdomain=N/A deviceip=192.168.188.161 devicemac=**-**-**-**-**-** site=N/A fctver=7.2.2.0864 fgtserial=FCT************* emsserial=N/A os="Microsoft Windows 11 , 64-bit (build 22621)" user=yk_th msg="Update was successful to the given version for the given module"
11/30/2023 9:15:34 AM   error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 13116: RasGetEntryPropertiesWin7(fortissl) failed. (r=623)
11/30/2023 9:15:34 AM   error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 13116: error: ssl_connect:-3
11/30/2023 9:15:34 AM   error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 13116: tunnel_to_fgt error
11/30/2023 9:15:36 AM   error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 4060: error: ras_loop(), waitResult=1.
11/30/2023 9:16:05 AM   info    sslvpn  date=2023-11-30 time=09:16:04 logver=1 id=96600 type=securityevent subtype=sslvpn eventtype=status level=info uid=*************** devid=FCT************* hostname=SYT pcdomain=N/A deviceip=192.168.188.161 devicemac=**-**-**-**-**-** site=N/A fctver=7.2.2.0864 fgtserial=FCT************* emsserial=N/A os="Microsoft Windows 11 , 64-bit (build 22621)" user=yk_th msg="SSLVPN tunnel status" vpnstate=disconnected vpntunnel="***"
11/30/2023 9:17:07 AM   info    system  date=2023-11-30 time=09:17:06 logver=1 id=96823 type=systemevent subtype=system eventtype=status level=info uid=*************** devid=FCT************* hostname=SYT pcdomain=N/A deviceip=192.168.188.161 devicemac=**-**-**-**-**-** site=N/A fctver=7.2.2.0864 fgtserial=FCT************* emsserial=N/A os="Microsoft Windows 11 , 64-bit (build 22621)" user=yk_th msg="Checking for updates"
11/30/2023 9:17:12 AM   info    sslvpn  date=2023-11-30 time=09:17:11 logver=1 id=96600 type=securityevent subtype=sslvpn eventtype=status level=info uid=*************** devid=FCT************* hostname=SYT pcdomain=N/A deviceip=192.168.188.161 devicemac=**-**-**-**-**-** site=N/A fctver=7.2.2.0864 fgtserial=FCT************* emsserial=N/A os="Microsoft Windows 11 , 64-bit (build 22621)" user=yk_th msg="SSLVPN tunnel status" vpnstate=disconnected vpntunnel=***"
```

Comment: What @Ramhound says; disable IPv6. Many FortiNet servers are strictly IPv4 so they will choke on IPv6. But have you ever successfully connected with FortiClient before? Or is this the first time you are attempting to connect with it?

Comment: There are also other potential reasons for this exact same error, if [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1678315/why-does-forticlient-vpn-stops-connecting-at-98), actually answers your question you can flag your own question as a duplicate. If I were to guess, the author of that question was likely using a IPv6 proxy, but that’s just an educated guess

Answer (score 0):

> I'm currently facing an issue with my FortiClient VPN, where it consistently gets stuck at 98% during the connection process. Despite numerous attempts, I haven't been able to pinpoint the root cause or find a solution.

Disabling IPv6 on the client machine should resolve the issue.

> This issue usually occurs due to IPv6 being enabled on the NIC of the client machine.
>
> It can be resolved by disabling IPv6 on the NIC of the client machine.

Source: [Here](https://community.fortinet.com/t5/FortiGate/Technical-Tip-SSL-VPN-fails-at-98/ta-p/248363)